# How to get the values of a selected row in the Advanced DataGrid control in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How to get the values of a selected row in the Advanced DataGrid control in Flex ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'SelectedCells' property will help you here.

You can learn more on this at
 'http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGrid.html#eventSummary'

Click any cell in the row to select the row. After the selection, selectedCells contains a single Object:

[{rowIndex:selectedRowIndex, columnIndex: -1}]

Hope that helps.

Ashine.